# Acumatica update lot/serial number details later

Tags: acumatica

To my knowledge Acumatica do not have a master data screen for lot/serial numbers i can access like say vendors and items.  We can enter a lot number when the purchase receipt is created but later we cannot amend the expiry date for example.  Is there a screen where I can access lot number created and modify expiry date?
Thanks

Comment: Is this question about programming?

Comment: this appears to be a general application usage question - not a technical/programming question. As for the question - I am not aware of any screen or process that would allow this.

Comment: It is a question about general use of Acumatica ERP product and not a programming question. Questions on how to make a screen for such use case would be on topic for SO.